# Does App Store accept self signed certificate apps?

Tags: ios, ssl

i am a newbie whom developing an app for iOS (and also android i have talked it also for google play) which implemented a socket connection and had to allow all host in order to work with our self-signed certificate installed on server by editing the plist file (NSAllowsArbitraryLoads true) or i need define NSExceptionDomains ?.. 
in 2016 and before apple still accept it ( i have deployed 1 before ), but i heard there is new regulation for 2017.

Will App Store accept self signed certificate connection for 2017 ? Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only high level API's (e.g. NSURLSession, NSURLConnection, etc.) require app transport security.

[Low level stuff like POSIX sockets do not use ATS](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/48979#183384).